# django forloop.counter operation

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I would like to know how to replicate this in django:

```
for photo in gallery
    if counter is 1 
        then use this photo
     endif
endfor
```

how do I check the forloop counter if it is "1"?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
{% for photo in gallery %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
       Do something with {{ photo }}.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

this is equivalent to:

```
{% for photo in gallery %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
       Do something with {{ photo }}.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Reference: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)